# Difference between ~/Library/Application Scripts/ and ~/Library/Scripts

Tags: macos, automation

Does the two folders ~/Library/Application Scripts/ and  ~/Library/Scripts have different meanings? I’m considering where to put scripts for OmniFocus.

Answer (score 4):

The "Scripts" folder I believe is a relic from the past.

Scripts should now be placed in the "Application Scripts" folder. Make a folder within named after the bundle identifier (eg. com.apple.mail), and place scripts that you want to be used for that specific application.

Comment: Where do scripts put in the "Application Scripts" folder appear? In other words, how do we use them?

Comment: what are the different between library application and library database?